# google maps issue php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

i have integrated google map in my sit it's working fine only but, when i'm searching particular area that  particular area is showing but down only showing,
 i need center point of the searching particular area map please help some one i have tried lang time.

Here google map javascript code:

```
<div class="map">
      <div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBAM5Cs2VsrOBs8Idqy0t0o6vw4hEU0Lys">
 </script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var delay = 100;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12.5,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    gestureHandling: 'none',
    zoomControl: false,
    gestureHandling: 'greedy'
  }
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  function geocodeAddress(address, next) {
    geocoder.geocode({address:address}, function (results,status)
      { 
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var p = results[0].geometry.location;
          var lat=p.lat();
          var lng=p.lng();
          createMarker(address,lat,lng);
        }
        else {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            nextAddress--;
            delay++;
          } else {
                }   
        }
        next();
      }
    );
  }
 function createMarker(add,lat,lng) {
   var contentString = add;
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
     draggable: true,
     map: map,
           });
    marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
    function toggleBounce() {
        if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
          marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
          marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
      }
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
     infowindow.open(map,marker);
   });
   bounds.extend(marker.position);
 }
 var locations = <?= $locations ?>;
console.log(locations);
  var nextAddress = 0;
  function theNext() {
    if (nextAddress < locations.length) {
      setTimeout('geocodeAddress("'+locations[nextAddress]+'",theNext)', delay);
      nextAddress++;
    } else {
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }
  theNext();

</script>
    </div>
```

Here style :

```
<style>
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: grey;

      }
    </style>
```

Comment: Very hard to understand what the question is. Please try to rephrase it or ask someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript function `map.setCenter(latLngObject);` 
See the documentation
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference